# Packaging source files from around my computer

Tags: c++, linux

I'm writing an application in C++ for a university assignment and I need to compress the source files in a zip file and email them to my supervisor for assessment. The problem is I have a 'toolbox' in a separate directory that contains a custom namespace that contains a lot of functions and classes I've found myself rewriting for every assignment, such as error/sanity checking a user's input.

Is there a tool that will create a compressed file containing all the source files that are stored in different locations? My compiler is able to follow the directories specified in my preamble, so I imagine there would be a tool out there that could to this. I'm writing this app on Linux, in C++, and would prefer a CLI tool but will settle for a GUI if that's what there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably is, but the easiest thing to do is write a short script that copies everything into a temporary directory, then zips that directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`gcc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) or [`cpp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cpp) in dependency mode. For example `cpp -MM` produces Makefile rules for C files:

```
$ cpp -MM abstract.c
abstract.o: abstract.c differ.h overrides.h debug.h settings.h abstract.h \
 abstract/posix.h abstract/linux.h misc.h command.h queue.h list.h \
 storage.h sqlite3.h
```

You can parse this output to get a list of the included files. `cpp` works fine with C++ source files, as well, so you should have no problems in that front.

You should take care to provide the same preprocessor options as when compiling normally, however.

EDIT:

Since `zip` updates files with the same name within an archive, you could use something like this:

```
$ for i in *.c *.cc; do cpp -MM "$i"; done | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | grep -v ':$' | xargs -r zip test.zip
updating: test2.cc (deflated 61%)
  adding: greater.c (deflated 38%)
  adding: test.cc (deflated 61%)
  adding: yyy.h (stored 0%)
  adding: zzz.h (stored 0%)
$ for i in *.c *.cc; do cpp -MM "$i"; done | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | grep -v ':$' | xargs -r zip test.zip
updating: test2.cc (deflated 61%)
updating: greater.c (deflated 38%)
updating: test.cc (deflated 61%)
updating: yyy.h (stored 0%)
updating: zzz.h (stored 0%)
```

This stores the files that are included in the specified source files, along with the source files themselves, in a `zip` archive. Note that you have to take care, so that each source file is processed with the correct `cpp` options.

Answer (score 1):

The zip command takes multiple files as input. So you could do

zip project.zip my_project_dir my_toolbox_dir

If you want just source files, you can do

zip project.zip my_project_dir my_toolbpx_dir/*.cpp